# Checking if an object attribute is set - SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, object, simplexml

I have some XML I am using PHP's SimpleXML class with and I have elements within the XML such as:

```
<condition id="1" name="New"></condition>
<condition id="2" name="Used"></condition>
```

However they are not always there, so I need to check if they exist first.

I have tried..

```
if (is_object($bookInfo->page->offers->condition['used'])) {
    echo 'yes';
}
```

as well as..

```
if (isset($bookInfo->page->offers->condition['used'])) {
    echo 'yes';
}
```

But neither work. They only work if I remove the attribute part.

So how can I check to see if an attribute is set as part of an object?

Comment: wait...I can add multiple attributes to xml element? How can I do this with simplexml, please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're looking at is the attribute value. You need to look at the attribute (`name` in this case) itself:

```
if (isset($bookInfo->page->offers->condition['name']) && $bookInfo->page->offers->condition['name'] == 'Used')
    //-- the rest is up to you
```

Comment: how `$bookInfo->page->offers->condition['name'] == 'Used'` works? takes each matching(1st cond) path of the xml and then approch the second matching condition?

Answer (score 8):

Actually, you should really use [SimpleXMLElement::attributes()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php), but you should check the Object afterwards using [isset()](http://php.net/isset):

```
$attr = $bookInfo->page->offers->condition->attributes();
if (isset($attr['name'])) {
    //your attribute is contained, no matter if empty or with a value
}
else {
    //this key does not exist in your attributes list
}
```

Comment: is this solution more lightweight then above one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SimpleXMLElement::attributes()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

```
$attr = $bookInfo->page->offers->condition->attributes();

if ($attr['name'] == 'Used') {
  // ...
```