# How to compare Two XML files for same atribute names by php

Tags: php, xml

I have two XML files `string1.xml` and `string2.xml` every file contain the more line codes. I want to Compare Two XML files according to same attr names

I want iterate loop for all lines like this expression below

```
if (attribute name cancel in string1.xml also found in string2.xml) {
    echo '<string name="attrName from string1.xml">Atribute Value from string2.xml</string>'
} else {
    echo '<string name="attrName from string1.xml">Atribute Value from string1.xml</string>'
}
```

string1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="cancel">Cancel</string>
    <string name="copy">Copy</string>
    <string name="copyUrl">Copy URL</string>
</resources>
```

string2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="cancel">US</string>
    <string name="paste">Italy</string>
    <string name="copyUrl">Germany</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Will the keys always match? Have you tried using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) yet? Is the structure always a single layer or can it be multiple layers deep?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699821/php-check-if-xml-node-exists-with-attribute

Comment: Here see how to check a attribute is available or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909372/checking-if-an-object-attribute-is-set-simplexml

Comment: @mkaatman yes structure always a single layer I tried SimpleXML of single XML file but I tried to compare to files I failed I can't create correct foreach loop for iterate over all lines in both files

Comment: @mkaatman two files have the small bit different in attribute names but completely different in attribute values

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php

$resource1 = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$resource2 = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$array1 = $resource1->string;
$array2 = $resource2->string;

$differences = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

Or maybe you could loop through the first one looking for items in the 2nd.

`foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $array2) && $array1[$key] === $array2[$key] ) {
        echo "$key is the same.";
    }
}`